# Download multiple files one at a time with progress in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am using vb.net. I need to download multiple files, but one at a time with download progress. I tried using downloadfile and downloadfileasync, but I must be doing something wrong, because the second file always sits at 0kb.

Thanks in Advance 
Kris

```
Dim downloadClient As New WebClient()
downloadClient.Headers("Accept") = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
downloadClient.Headers("User-Agent") = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.83 Safari/537.1"
Dim dnldurl As String = "www.xyz.com/123.csv"
downloadClient.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri(dnldurl), ("C:\bhav_csv.zip"))
While (downloadClient.IsBusy = True)
End While

Dim result As Integer = MessageBox.Show("Data Downloaded for the date!!! Download more?", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)

    If result = DialogResult.No Then
        Me.Dispose()
    End If
```

The user has to select the next file and to continue the process. But from the second one onwards, it would not download the file, or the downloaded file size would be 0kb.

Comment: Can you post what you have already tried?

Comment: Always [**edit**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44950442/edit) your question when adding code. It is impossible to read in the comments. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Really Sorry, I am not so familiar. I have edited and added the codes

Comment: In your example you download one file and wait for it until it is done. How did you trigger the download of the second file?

Comment: Next file is to be selected and triggered by user

Comment: Then you need to show us that code as well.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. The main code is edited to add the user interference to select the subsequent files.